# Derivative of $r(t) = <t\sin4t, t^2, t\cos6t>$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

When I do the derivative of $r(t) = <t\sin4t, t^2, t\cos6t>$, I get $r'(t) = (\sin4t + 4t\cos4t, 2t, \cos6t - 6t\sin6t)$
, but it's supposedly "wrong." If so, I must have some fundamental misunderstanding of what's going on. Please confirm that I'm not crazy.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks. I hate webassign!!!

Comment: I concur with my colleague Bongers. Looks good to me as well!